# copy_to_user and copy_from_user with structs

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I have a simple question: when i have to copy a structure's content from userspace to kernel space for example with an ioctl call (or viceversa) (for simplicity code hasn't error check):

```
typedef struct my_struct{
 int a;
 char b;
} my_struct;
```

Userspace:

```
my_struct s;
s.a = 11;
s.b = 'X';

ioctl(fd, MY_CMD, &s);
```

Kernelspace:

```
int my_ioctl(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp, unsigned int cmd,
             unsigned long arg)
{
...
    my_struct ks;
    copy_from_user(&ks, (void __user *)arg, sizeof(ks));
...
}
```

i think that size of structure in userspace (variable `s`) and kernel space (variable `ks`) could be not the same (without specify the `__attribute__((packed))`). So is a right thing specifing the number of byte in `copy_from_user` with `sizeof` macro? I see that in kernel sources there are some structures that are not declared as packed so, how is ensured the fact that the size will be the same in userspace and kernelspace?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Why should the layout of a struct be different in kernel space from user space? There is no reason for the compiler to layout data differently. 
The exception is if userspace is a 32bit program running on a 64bit kernel. See http://www.x86-64.org/pipermail/discuss/2002-June/002614.html for a tutorial how to deal with this.

Comment: Because, for example, you could have a kernel builded with a compiler an the application compiled with another one that chooses to pack the structures. However thank you for the link! Very interesting...

Comment: Fact is that the struct and it's layout is part of the kernel ABI, defined by the kernel.
Actually this is a fine example of the brokenness of the ioctl() interface.

Comment: Is it not, in general, unsafe to assume that structs are layed out in memory in any particular way?

Answer (score 1):

The userspace structure should come from kernel header, so struct definition should be the same in user and kernel space. Do you have any real example ?

Of course, if you play with different packing options on two side of an ABI, whatever it is, you are in trouble. The problem here is not sizeof.

If your question is : does packing options affect binary interface, the answer is yes.
If your question is, how can I solve a packing mismatch, please provide more information

Comment: The first example could be the userspace application that defines a vector of two structures: `my_struct vec[2]` and that is builded with `-fpack-struct` switch. If, when the kernel module (where the `my_ioctl` is defined) is builded, the compiler doesn't pack the structure (this is very likely) a `copy_to_user` called with `sizeof(my_struct)` as third arg and the address `vec` as first arg will write also the second item in userspace variable `vec`. Am i right?

Comment: Maybe the question could be also: Is possible that, building a userspace application, the compiler chooses to pack structures also without the `-fpack-struct` flag so in a difference way than it did compiling the kernel? And: how does the compiler know that `my_struct` could be used in a `ioctl` syscall? Thank you shodanex!