# c - copy_to_user: how to read a struct type value of kernel space in the user space?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I have a kernel module where I would like to pass some values into User Space. Someone suggested me to use struct type to pass more values.
In kernel space I have:

```
typedef struct data {
        int val_delta;
        int val_btn_status;
}data_t;

static ssize_t sample_read(struct file *filp, char *buffer, size_t length, loff_t * offset)
{
    int ret = 1;
    int delta = 10;
    data_t val;

    val.val_btn_status = gpio_get_value( BTN );
    val.val_delta = delta;

    copy_to_user( buffer, &val, sizeof(data_t)); 

    return( ret );
}
```

In User space how can I take the two values into data_t struct?
I thought to declare also in User Space the data_t type as:

```
typedef struct data {
        int val_delta;
        int val_btn_status;
}data_t;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    data_t str;
    char *app_name = argv[0];
    char *dev_name = "/dev/sample";
    int fd = -1;

    if ((fd = open(dev_name, O_RDWR)) < 0) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: unable to open %s: %s\n", app_name, dev_name, strerror(errno));
        return( 1 );
    }

    x = read(fd, &str, 1);

    return 0;
}
```

but I don't like this because I wouldn't like to rewrite both on User Space and on Kernel Space the same typedef, and maybe this one doesn't work. There are other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `common struct` and the `dev_name` in to a header and include in the driver and the user space program.

Like: **data.h**

```
#ifndef DATA_H
#define DATA_H    

typedef struct data {
    int val_delta;
    int val_btn_status;
}data_t;

#define dev_name "/dev/sample"

#endif
```

Also change

```
read(fd, &str, 1);
```

to

```
read(fd, &str, sizeof(data_t));
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I don't prefer header (also it is a good solution) because in the program I have to be faster as possible otherwise the program freezes.
My program manages a distance sensor (HC-SR04). This sensor, when it receives a TRIGGER signal for at least 10 us, it makes sure to begin ECHO signal that I use to compute the measurements.
In my kernel module I use write function to set TRIGGER and read funct to read the time duration of ECHO and compute the distance. I'm afraid that with the call to typedef, when I declare the struct (also into a .h), I lose time and freeze the program

Comment: Adding a header will not affect runtime of the program. If your program freezes there has to be another problem. Because anything to do with the header file is done at the time of preprocessing

Comment: Ok now I try. Before I noted that when I write the typedef into kernel space, program freezes. When I delete it, the program run correctly. However I try and say you :)

Comment: Ok the program works correctly also in term of time xD Thank you Santosh. Thanks also to askb.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to understand the [`copy_to_user()` def](http://www.hep.by/gnu/kernel/kernel-api/API-copy-to-user.html).

```
unsigned long copy_to_user (    void __user * to,
    const void * from,
    unsigned long n);
```

In your sample `sample_read()` function should use `char __user *buffer` instead of `char *buffer`.

Put your `typedef struct data` definition into a header file which can be included both kernel module and user program instead of redefining it twice.

[Refer to thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457574/copy-to-user-and-copy-from-user-with-structs)

Comment: Thank you for answer. I don't prefer header (also it is a good solution) because in the program I have to be faster as possible otherwise the program freezes.
My program manages a distance sensor (HC-SR04). This sensor, when it receives a TRIGGER signal for at least 10 us, it makes sure to begin ECHO signal that I use to compute the measurements.
In my kernel module I use write function to set TRIGGER and read funct to read the time duration of ECHO and compute the distance. I'm afraid that with the call to typedef, when I declare the struct (also into a .h), I lose time and freeze the program

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried other options, like marking your ECHO interrupt from the sensor (I'm assuming that it'll be an interrupt) as a fast interrupt so it won't be pre-empted by others at the same level. 
Or why not have it at the highest available interrupt level on your processor (beneath the hard coded ones). 
As Santosh says there has to be a different reason for the freeze. Perhaps have you looked at the alignment of your given structure? In accordance to your underlying processor's word length??